# How do you define a nested templated class' method outside of the class declaration?

Tags: c++, templates

How do I define `func` outside of the class declaration, below `class A{...};`?

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
    template<typename Q>
    class B
    {
        static void func(const A<T>& a){} // How do I define this function outside of the class declaration?
    };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a double template:

```
template<typename T>
template<typename Q>
void A<T>::B<Q>::func(const A<T>& a)
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's fairly straight-forward:

```
template<typename T>
template<typename Q>
void A<T>::B<Q>::func(const A<T>& a) { }
```

Basically it's the same technique as defining a templated class method outside the declaration of a class template.  For instance:

```
template<typename T>
class test
{
    template<typename U>
    void func(const U& u);
};
```

You would define `func` outside the class like so:

```
template<typename T>
template<typename U>
void test<T>::func(const U& u) { }
```

Comment: Even after all this time, I found few things about templates straight-forward :)

Comment: Yep, dunno what I was thinking - why didn't I try that?! lol, thanks.

Comment: @Luchian : Yeah, I definitely agree ... but this one at least makes sense :-)